# Hover over Dropdownlist HTML5 looking for a specific code

Tags: html

I want to make a form with dropdownlists like the ones on the site Nafham.com website exactly (with the headers on hover on first one and multiple columns). Are there any ready scripts for that? Is it possible to do the exact thing in Twitter Bootstrap? I am new to HTML5 so I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions that don't show any research effort are likely to stay unanswered or get closed.

Which technology do you want to use to achieve this?

Comment: I tried looking for scripts for dropdownlists on bootstrap documentation and google for a long while. I found the horizontal ones but no multiple verticals. I can easily do the lists with flash but I want to migrate to HTML5 since I am starting to learn it. I tried stripping the code from CSS/HTML from the website itself but I do not want to steal the code. That is why I am asking here. I want a sample to actually use and understand. I am not a designer and that is my problem. I develop in many languages but when it comes to animations and graphics. I am not that good. Thanks.

Comment: This is a site for posting problems, and not for ordering a code. Go to your favorit search engine, and search... then when you have a problem come to us..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to your comment above, there is a [difference between stealing and gaining inspiration](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/inspired-by-copied-from/). So far for Off-Topic

When i understand you correctly, you want a dropdown menu with multiple columns. This can be relatively easy done with simple CSS. Learn about basic CSS and try to implent your own version, based on the [bootstrap dropdown](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html), if you like.

Correct me if i missed anything.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the menu works (the visual part). So, the CSS actually shapes the resulting dropdownlists including the headers and multiple columns. They are already available and hidden on the webpage and when I hover over them their visibility is changed and they are shown. Did I understand this right?

Comment: @JohnB.
Yes, that is correct. This could for example be accomplished by adding and removing css classes or using the css pseudo-selector :hover
If you are interested in this topic, i can heavily recommend the MDN CSS section. If i can help you any further, feel free to ask. sprottenwels@googlemail.com